# Windows console command for finding server site is deployed to

Tags: cmd, ip-address

I have a url to a site and I vaguely remember there being a Windows console command that you can use to find the IP address of the server the site is deployed to.  Can someone remind me?  Also, can you tell me how to use it?

Comment: I use `ping domainname.com` as a shortcut, it will resolve the domain name before starting requests

Comment: I seriously doubt you're using DOS. Do you mean the Windows command prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you ping the server using the Windows command prompt, it will gives you the server IP.
ex.: ping www.google.com

```
C:\Users\Deleu>ping www.google.com

Pinging www.l.google.com [177.99.189.241] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 177.99.189.241: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=58
Reply from 177.99.189.241: bytes=32 time=36ms TTL=58
Reply from 177.99.189.241: bytes=32 time=38ms TTL=58
Reply from 177.99.189.241: bytes=32 time=38ms TTL=58

Ping statistics for 177.99.189.241:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 34ms, Maximum = 38ms, Average = 36ms

C:\Users\Deleu>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [nslookup](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200525).

> Nslookup.exe is a command-line administrative tool for testing and
>   troubleshooting DNS servers. This tool is installed along with the
>   TCP/IP protocol through Control Panel. This article includes several
>   tips for using Nslookup.exe.

```
c:\Temp>nslookup google.com
Server:  BoB.Orcon
Address:  10.1.1.1  <------ Name server 

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2404:6800:4006:804::1004    <----- Answer in ipv6
          74.125.237.128                <----- Answer in ipv4
          74.125.237.137                <----- Other answers....
          74.125.237.134                          .
          74.125.237.132                          .
          74.125.237.135                          .
          74.125.237.133                         etc
          74.125.237.136                          .
          74.125.237.142                          .
          74.125.237.130                          .
          74.125.237.131                          .
          74.125.237.129
```